# set up complete c++ environment with conda

Tags: c++, conda

I am trying to set up complete c++ environment with conda. So that every c++ dependency can be installed (within conda environment) without adding -L -I etc. And my computer should be able to detect all the dependencies. Is it possible? Thank you.

Comment: You can use conda to download the dependencies, but you still need to link to the relevant libraries. Can you post your meta.yaml and build.sh